# $firebaseSimpleLogin() for facebook doesn't work when preferRedirect is true

Tags: angularfire

**Scenario:**

- Ensure not currently logged into Facebook
- Navigate to webapp on localhost
- Click "login" and it properly takes you to the Facebook login screen without using a pop-up
- Login using valid credentials
- Automatically redirect back to localhost
- Doesn't appear to be logged in and auth.user is null
- Click login again and the request is cancelled automatically by firebase
- Navigate to facebook (and may need to refresh) and you are logged in, so the login did "work"

If you use `preferRedirect:false` the entire scenario works as expected

**Versions:**

- angular and angular-route: 1.3.0-b14
- firebase, firebase-simple-login, and angularfire: 1.0.17

**Code snippets**

```
/* html snippet */
<div id="login">
  <span ng-show="auth.user">
    {{auth.user.id}} | <a href="#" ng-click="facebookLogout()">Logout</a>
  </span>
  <a href="#" ng-hide="auth.user" ng-click="facebookLogin()">Login</a>
</div>


/* javascript snippet */
angular.module('<removed_for_this_post>', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])
.value('firebaseURL', 'https://<removed_for_this_post>.firebaseio.com/')
.factory('FirebaseData', function(firebaseURL) {
  return (new Firebase(firebaseURL));
})
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller:'HomeCtrl',
      templateUrl:'home.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
})

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, FirebaseData, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<removed_for_this_post>.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

    /* Login using facebook */
    $scope.facebookLogin = function() {
        $scope.auth.login('facebook', {
            rememberMe: true,
            preferRedirect: true
        }); 
    };

    /* Logout using facebook */
    $scope.facebookLogout = function() {
        $scope.auth.$logout();  
    };

});
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you [tried upgrading to the latest simple login version, as this thread suggests?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/preferredirect/firebase-talk/iLMzPzERAL0/hnbQNb70p-0J)

Comment: I just tested these exact steps on my local machine with the latest versions of all libraries and it worked as expected:

(1) AngularFire: 0.7.1
(2) Firebase: 1.0.17
(3) Firebase Simple Login: 1.6.2

Please make sure you are using the latest version of Simple Login.

Comment: I have AngularFire: 0.7.1, Firebase: 1.0.21, Firebase Simple Login: 1.6.3. I think I have the same problem, here... Using `preferRedirect: true` seems to execute the full oAuth process (without popup), but something bad happens (I even have no more console.logs messages!!!). This is true for google, facebook and twitter providers...